# Sort set of array in ascending order in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to write a code to actually sort my array in an ascending order, so what happen is that say this is what I have.

```
char myListArray[10][40];
myListArray = "Yeah?",
              "Tomorrow",
              "Again",
              "I will see you";
```

So what happen is that it should be sort in the order by ASCII value.

```
Again
I will see you
Tomorrow
Yeah?
```

I've create something like this...

```
char temp[40];
temp[0] = '\0';           
int i, j, pos = 10, flag = 1;

for(i = 1; (i <= pos) && flag; i++)
{
    flag = 0;
    for (j=0; j < (pos -1); j++)
    {
        if (phrase[i][j+1] > phrase[i][j])     
        {
            strcpy(temp, phrase[i]);
            strcpy(phrase[i], phrase[i+1]);
            strcpy(phrase[i+1], temp);
            flag = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I don't know I have a problem with my logic, and I wish to know if there is a function to sort easy way? or `bubble sort` is the easiest ?

UPDATE:

I will accept one of the answer below, but I have found my solution of how to sort my array in the easiest way.

```
while(pos < 9){

  if(phrase[pos][i] > phrase[pos+1][i]){


   strcpy(temp, phrase[pos]);
   strcpy(phrase[pos], phrase[pos+1]);
   strcpy(phrase[pos+1], temp);
   flag = 1;

 if(flag = 1){

    pos = 0;

  }


  }

pos++;

}
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: @trumpetlicks yeah, I actually saw that when I search and thought that bubble sort is slowest, but I guest my code above consider as bubble sort too?

Comment: Yes, Im pretty sure you are implementing a bubble sort!!!

Comment: @trumpetlicks and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Here is the bubble sort algorithm link,  Just all but copy this code.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Comment: @trumpetlicks is that in C++?

Comment: Its in algorithmic form, you will still need to convert it to C or C++ whichever you are trying to stick with!!!

Comment: @ali If you're allowed to use functions I'd definitely take advantage of that. For bubble sort it's standard practice to create a `swap(element1, element2)` function to swap two elements.

Comment: @trumpetlicks I wish I know how to do that because I'm still new with C and C++

Comment: @Michael can you explain a bit more? My professor didn't say if we are restricted to any of the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `std::array`, `std::string`, and `std::sort`...

```
std::array<std::string, 4> arr = { "Yeah?", "Tomorrow", "Again", "I will see you" };
std::sort(arr.begin(), arr.end());
```

This can also be trivially adapted to use C arrays or `std::vectors` if you don't have access to `std::array`.

Comment: And what if in my above case? I mean if all of those string is store in array call `phrase` which is `2D` array then how can I sort them?

Comment: @Ali : `std::sort(phrase.begin(), phrase.end());`..? Or do you mean C-array?

Comment: @ildjarn well, I'm not sure that is the thing but when I try it I have this error `error: 'sort' is not a member of 'std'`

Comment: @Ali : `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: @ildjarn, now I'm getting this error instead. `error: request for member 'begin' in '((segment*)this)->segment::phrase', which is of non-class type 'char [10][40]'
`

Comment: @Ali : You're not using `std::array<>` as this answer suggested to, nor are you using `std::string`. Why ignore 3/4 of the answer?

Comment: @ildjarn well I'm confuse about that let me try and see if I can include those two and it will be working. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ildjarn could that error means I can't use sort to access the data?

Comment: @Ali : That error means that your datatype is `char[10][40]` rather than `std::array<std::string, 4>` as the answer says to use.

Comment: @ildjarn sorry, but I don't understand why I have to use that array while my data is in `phrase` and when I include that I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: @Ali : You don't have to use that, you only have to use that if you take the approach that this answer suggests (`std::sort`). If you don't want to change your underlying datatype then this answer isn't going to be of much use to you (except to tell you that there's a better way to do it than what you're trying).

Comment: @ildjarn honestly I didn't sleep for 2 days now because I'm working on this assignment and really I have create and remove the function for more than 10 times, but I guess I'm wrong in some place that makes my code not working properly

Answer (score 1):

> I wish to know if there is a function to sort easy way?

- Try to use C++ constructs such as `string`, `vector` and `sort`. Your job becomes much easier then.
- However, if you want to use C, you can look up `qsort`. You will need to provide a custom comparator function though.

> bubble sort is the easiest ?

The choice of a sorting algorithm depends on factors such as worst-case performance, number of elements etc. Think about the number of elements that you need to sort. Think what sort of performance will be acceptable. IMO, implementing bubble-sort is about as easy as insertion-sort or Shell-sort. Merge sort/quick sort/radix sort OTOH, are perhaps slightly more involved.

Comment: Thank I will look up for those functions while trying to fix my own function which the logic kinda messed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to use plain C, like you seem to, then you are missing out on `strcmp` and `qsort`. Note that your code has *nothing to do* with C++, it's a classic C code and the question is mistagged. If you want it done in C++, see other answers that actually use C++ containers. There's no point to using C++ if you don't actually, you know, use the part that makes it C++, not merely C!

Below is a self contained working example. Note that there is an example both for your 2D array and for an array of pointers to strings. Your 2D array declaration had a superfluous 1st array size. It's unnecessary, the compiler knows how many strings are there.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort1(void)
{
    // 2D array
    char strings[][40] = {
        "Yeah?",
        "Tomorrow",
        "Again",
        "I will see you"
    };
    const int el_size = sizeof(strings[0]);
    const int el_count = sizeof(strings)/el_size;
    int i;
    printf("\n%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    qsort(strings, el_count, el_size, strcmp);
    for (i = 0; i < el_count; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
}

int strcmp_ptr(const char ** a, const char ** b)
{
    return strcmp(*a, *b);
}

void sort2(void)
{
    // Array of pointers to string constants
    const char * strings[] = {
        "Yeah?",
        "Tomorrow",
        "Again",
        "I will see you"
    };
    const int el_size = sizeof(strings[0]);
    const int el_count = sizeof(strings)/el_size;
    int i;
    printf("\n%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    qsort(strings, el_count, el_size, strcmp_ptr);
    for (i = 0; i < el_count; ++i) {
        printf("%s\n", strings[i]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    sort1();
    sort2();
    return 0;
}
```